# Redirect to same page from where it is called

Tags: grails, redirect

I have a action, say `default` which will be called from different `gsp` page.
This `default` have different set of operation, After completing this operation it need to redirect to the same page from where it is called. Is there any way to achieve this
For example :
A.gsp -> `<g:link controller="myController" action="default">`
Then `default` should redirect to A.gsp

B.gsp -> `<g:link controller="myController" action="default">`
Then `default` should redirect to B.gsp

I know to implement by sending some params value or other to identify the caller.
But I'm checking is there any way to redirect to caller directly without passing anything from caller explicitly...

Answer (score 0):

You could write a taglib that will use `g.link` and [`actionName` variable](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.3.1%20Variables%20and%20Scopes).